# Comparing Realm Results and finding the object in a List

Tags: swift, realm

I need to loop through the objects in the Realm file and see if it is also listed in the List.

When I look at the file with the Realm Browser, it is there, but the following code always renders false.

Can anyone make out what is going on? (I am initiating Try! Realm earlier in the code, it is there, this is just the section that is bobbling my brian. It runs fine BTW.

Thanks,
Blessings,
—Mark

```
    let totalReg = realm.objects(Registry.self)
    let totalList = realm.objects(AllServices.self)

    if totalReg.count != 0 && totalList.count != 0 { // when the update releases, I will change totalList == 0

        print(totalReg.count) // = 2 records
        print(totalList.count) // = 1 but when I click and open the list in Realm Browser it shows both records

        let a = AllServices().self

        for reg in totalReg {
            if a.everything.contains(reg) {

                print("Here")
            } else {
                print("not here") //Each loop goes here.
                print(a.everything) //this prints: List<Registry> <0x600001d6e070> ( )
                print (reg) //This correctly prints all the properties of the object.
            }
        }
    }
```

This code always defaults to false, even though the Registry Object is in the List.

```
class Registry: Object {
    @objc dynamic var registryId = UUID().uuidString

    @objc dynamic var dateTime:String?
    @objc dynamic var proper:String?
    @objc dynamic var service:String?
    @objc dynamic var place:String?

    @objc dynamic var sunEuchAttendance:Int = 0

    @objc dynamic var otherServiceAttendance:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var EuchVisitor:Int = 0

    @objc dynamic var numberOfCommunions:Int = 0

    //People serving
    @objc dynamic var presiderOfficiant:String?
    @objc dynamic var preacher:String?
    @objc dynamic var server:String?
    @objc dynamic var memo:String?

    @objc dynamic var weekendEuch:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var weekdayEuch:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var privateEuch:Int = 0

    @objc dynamic var weekendOffice:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var weekdayOffice:Int = 0

    @objc dynamic var burrial:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var marraige:Int = 0

    @objc dynamic var other:Int = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "registryId"
    }

    override static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["service"]
    }
}
```

//List Model

```
class AllServices: Object {
    var everything = List<Registry>()
    var eucharist = List<Registry>()
    var weekdayEucharist = List<Registry>()
    var office = List<Registry>()
    var weekdayOffice = List<Registry>()
    var marriage = List<Registry>()
    var burial = List<Registry>()
    var requiem = List<Registry>()
    var nuptial = List<Registry>()
    var other = List<Registry>()
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear - *it is also listed in the List.* you're not using a List here - what does that mean? Also it looks like you are trying to compare two different types of Realm objects Registry and AllServices and you can't really do that like shown in the question. Also, what do you expect from this `if a.everything`? Can you clarify what you're doing?

Comment: Correct. I am trying to compare a Realm Results (Registry) and Realm List (AllServices). I am trying to determine if the List variable 'everything' is in the Results of Registry. If it is not there, I need to add that object to the list. I am just not sure how to do this comparison. Thanks.

Comment: A few things. You didn't include your Realm models but I think you're saying the AllServices Realm model has a List<Registry>() property. Also `let a = AllServices().self` means that `a` is a AllServices *model* and will not 'contain' anything other than default properties; think of it as a class e.g. `class User {}` then `a = User()` is just an empty user. Iterating over an array looking for an object feels a bit clunky. Using a filter to find that object will be a better solution. Can you provide some details about what object you're looking for? Maybe include you Realm Models as well?

Comment: Here is a link to the models:

https://gist.github.com/garageshop/5b8dfb184f32fc350213d807b9e46abe

I originally published the app with just the Registry Model. I have a tableview that presents the data in the model. In an update, I switch from Results to a List so I can present the data sorted and filtered by the type of service. I can migrate the app, no problem., but all the objects that is stored in Registry is not now available in the List. NEW entries are added to the list. What I need to do the first time a user opens the updated app is add all previous Registry objects to the List.

Comment: I did not realize that relpies needed to be so brief! 

I already have a method that will add the Registry opject as it loops through all of the objects, I just need to determine if it is there first. Thanks for you thoughts. I really appreciate it as I am really stuck!

Comment: Please do not use links in questions. They break and if they do, it invalidates the question. I added them for you. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: You can sort and filter Results as well as Lists. I think you best bet is to do this via a migration - the problem we have here is we don't know the relationship between the Registry and the which AllServices property it belongs to. However, I feel this is overcomplicated - why not just add a property to the Registry object indicating what kind of registry it is? `var registry_type = "office"` or `var registry_type = "marriage"` etc. You can easily sort and filter by that var and it greatly simplifies the code and structure.

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to add long chunks of text. This makes complete sense.

Comment: And thank you also for the suggestion to add a var toRegistry. It is already there, it is service. This is intrigiuing! If I abandong the List and fliter by the seervice variable, it may get me to exactly what I need. Thanks.